# split string based on regular expression value in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

suppose i have a string

```
exp = '"security_datafilter"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" IN ("CPU","Storage")'
```

I want to split the string based on word **IN**
so my exprected result is

```
['"security_datafilter"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"','IN','("CPU","Storage")']
```

but in my case it doesnt work
This is what i have tried

```
import re
exp_split = re.split(r'( in )',exp,re.I)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I):
`re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)`

The `split()` function expects that the third positional argument is the `maxsplit` argument. Your code gives `re.I` to `maxsplit` and no `flags`. You should give `flags` as a keyword argument like so:

```
exp_split = re.split(r'( in )',exp, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: so you literally copy pasted OP's attempt here. Have you even tried, if it work?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Yup I tried it on my py shell. Shree was on the right path, just missed the keyword params.

Comment: Hm, I see - just a note then - if OP wants to split by `IN` case insensitive, more appropriate would be `exp_split = re.split(r'(\bin\b)',exp,flags=re.I)` - so you can cater for `in` being at the end of the line, or syntax like `in(...)` assuming spaces as delimiter for `in` is a bit opportunistic.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Indeed! Thank you for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

its simply necessary to capitalize your delimiter and if you dont want the spaces in your result keep them outside your capturing group:

```
exp_split = re.split(r'\s(IN)\s', exp, re.I) 
exp_split
```

**Output**

```
['"security_datafilter"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"', 'IN', '("CPU","Storage")']
```